# Update realm file with new data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I am working on a quizz app and I use realm database to store all data (questions, answers, isUserAnswered, isUserAnsweredRight, etc...).
I set up a bundle file to persist all of these data in a realm file when the user launches the app for the first time.

I would like to add new questions in by database at each update. How to persist these new questions without overriding previous data already stored in db ? It's a problem to override because I store for each question if the user has answered and if he answered right. I don't want my users to lose all their progress at each update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not help but you could do one of a few things.

If your file contains primary keys for each object, as you are reading in the file, ignore the ones that match ones you already read in.

Another option is to version it - attach a version number to each object and only read in objects that are after the last read version.